# PHP MySql Can't insert if my fields are in relation

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called `tbl_schedule` which has 4 attributes namely:
`count_id(int)`, `room_id(int)`, `instructor_id(int)`, `subject_id(int)`.

This table is related to 3 tables which are: 
`tbl_room`, `tbl_instructor` and `tbl_subject`

The relation is :

- `tbl_schedule.room_id` is related to `tbl_room.room_id`,
- `tbl_schedule.instructor_id` is related to `tbl_instructor.instructor_id` and
- `tbl_schedule.subject`_id is related to `tbl_subject.subject_id`

I can't INSERT if my relationship are activated
but if i delete those relationships, it does SAVE now.

Is there any way I can do INSERT query while I have 3 related tables?

```
 "INSERT INTO tbl_schedule(room_id,instructor_id,subject_id)VALUES(1,1,1)"
```

Comment: Do you have a room record with id of 1, an instructor record with id of 1, and a subject record with an id of 1?

Comment: It also helps if you show the actual create statements for your tables and their relationships rather than simply describing them

Comment: Your tables "tbl_room, tbl_instructor and tbl_subject " must have a record (each table) with value of "1" in primary key column. Can you check that?